# How to remove size information, coming from check_http plugin output?

Tags: nagios, icinga

I am currently getting the following output while running `check_http`:

> HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 6654 bytes in 0.071 second response time
>   |time=0.070809s;200.000000;1000.000000;0.000000 size=6654B;;;0

How can I get it as :

> HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 6654 bytes in 0.071 second response time
>   |time=0.070809s;200.000000;1000.000000;0.000000

I know I can achieve  this by writing a script using awk's and sed's.

But I want to know if there is a way to tweak the output as per the requirement.

Comment: Why do you want to remove that? Everything after the pipe get's filtered under performance data in nagios.

Comment: What's your *real* question? I've done some strange things with nagios plugins over the years, but I can't think of a reason why you'd possibly want to do this.

Comment: @Keith: The reason for this requirement is because I am having issues in plotting graphs (NaN) in Icinga. And the solution seems to be by having it in the above  requested format.. This is just my view of things, which can be wrong.

Comment: You should ask that question, then. This is an XY Problem.

Answer (score 0):

As check_http is ELF binary and it seems there is no option to disable "size=..." or even whole perf output, I think there are two solutions to get rid of it:

- creating the wrapper script which you already mentioned about
- editing and recompiling sources

The latter is probably a way better approach in terms of performance.
The more servers you monitor, the more you should take it into account.